# ¿Por qué me sale este error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

El programa consiste en Para una lista de N elementos, que pueda recibir los nombres y la edades de N personas que el usuario ingresa por el teclado. Luego, que imprima un listado con las personas y sus edades, siempre que la edad sea mayor al promedio de las edades introducidas.

```
def lista_personas():

    nom = []
    edd = []
    no_personas = int(input("Cuantas personas quieres ingresar al sistema "))

    for i in range(no_personas):
        a1 = input("Ingrse el nombre de la persona: ")
        nom.append(a1)
        b2 = int(input("Ingrse la edad de la persona: "))
        edd.append(b2)
    return [nom,edd]

lista_p = nom + edd

def promedio_edades(edd):

    suma=0
    for i in range(len(edd)):
        suma=suma+ed[i]
    promedio=suma//no_personas

    if lista_p >= promedio :
        print("Los mayores del promedio son: ",lista_p)
```

el problema que tengo es que me sale el siguiente error:

> File "Practica_for.py", line 3, in 
>       no_personas = int(input("Cuantas personas quieres ingresar al sistema ")) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
>   'edddf'

Comment: Esta intentando convertir el texto `edddf` a un entero. Obviamente vas a tener un error.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es un problema del test realizado y no del código

Comment: Voto para mantener abierto. Los tests son una parte muy importante de la ingeniería del software, que es un tema muy relevante para este sitio.